move the Bool data type from x register to the D register in the Delta PLC(DIADesigner)
I am trying to move the bool data type of the X or Y registers(X0.0\Y0.0) to the D registers(D10000-which is a word/dword data type) so i can send the data from the PLC to the PC using TCP Socket communication. I am using the DIADesigner software. Is there any function blocks or conversion blocks to make this happen. I tried the MOVB, DMOV and BMOV blocks to do this, end up having error saying (incorrect data type) while compiling. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks in Advance.
